# javascript - windows.print() from modal show white space after the content

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, printing

I'm having this problem for a long time.
I'm printing a table which is inside of a modal, the content shown in the print preview is Ok, but after the table is a large chunk of white space.
[And look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJdnk.png)
It shows two pages in one just to explain my problem, and the gray background can be disabled with just unchecking background graphics.

This is the code I use to print and it's in my index, "_fields" is the Id of the div I want to print.

```
@section Scripts {
<script src="~/js/areas/human-resources/payrollmovement/index.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById("btn-print").onclick = function () {
            printElement("_fields");
        }

        function printElement(div) {
            // Create and insert new print section
            var elem = document.getElementById(div);
            var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
            var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
            $printSection.id = "printSection";
            $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
            document.body.insertBefore($printSection, document.body.firstChild);
            window.print();

            // Clean up print section for future use
            var oldElem = document.getElementById("printSection");
            if (oldElem != null) { oldElem.parentNode.removeChild(oldElem); }


            return true;
        }
    });
</script>}
```

This is my css

```
@media screen {
    #printSection {
    display: none;
    }
}

@media print {
body * {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#printSection, #printSection * {
    visibility: visible !important;
}

#printSection {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.modal-open .wrapper {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
}
```

I want to remove that white space after the table, and a way to duplicate the table.

Answer (score 0):

There are two plugins I've used that are designed to print portions of a page, so you should try them. No guarantee that they'll fix your problem but they're worth a try.

https://jasonday.github.io/printThis/

https://printjs.crabbly.com/

Comment: Thanks for the response, I already take other action angle for this problem... I will check both plugins for future projects.